# how to count search tweet per minute?

Tags: php, api, twitter

lets say i need to know how much people are search "something" per minute.

```
example 123 people is tweeting "something" per minute
```

**is there a way doing this?**

Thank you for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Have you looked at the twitter api?  http://dev.twitter.com/doc

Comment: yes i have, but i dont know where to start to do "per minute" thing. any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet will be to use Twitters streaming API. I've made a simple PHP wrapper around it ([tweetstream](https://github.com/alexandernyquist/Tweetstream), requires PHP 5.3). It's absolutely not finished but it should give you some ideas.

Using the Streaming API let's you track tweets containing defined keywords. Just insert those tweets into a database along with the posted time. From there it's trivial to do your calculations.

Example usage:

```
$streamer = new TweetStream();
$streamer->setCredentials('your username', 'your password');
$streamer->setCallback(function($message) {
    $message = sprintf('%s says: %s', $message->user->screen_name, $message->text);
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO tweets(message, timestamp) VALUES(.., ..)');
});
$streamer->track('something');
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can give you, if you already have code pulling in the tweets for the search term, is to setup a database and store the tweets in, with a `timestamp`. Then you just have to do a simple query and pull out the start time from the first entry, and the end time from the last entry and the number of twitter entries for that item.

From there you just calculate by taking the number of tweets, divided by the number of minutes. And viola, you have your Tweets per minute. For more information on how to pull tweets, see the [Twitter API Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if a Stream(SQL) implementation exists for PHP -- or, if your language requirement is flexible -- but I implemented something similar recently using Esper/JRuby/TweetStream using the info in this article:

http://www.igvita.com/2011/05/27/streamsql-event-processing-with-esper/